# Export mail from Gmail

Tags: python, gmail

At one point it was possible to use scripts like [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/) and gmail.py (can't post more than one hyperlink) to export mail from Gmail accounts.  Both of those seem to not work anymore — I can't even log in with them.  I assume it's because there's been some changes in Gmail.  Is there still any way to do this?

Comment: why can't you post more than one hyperlink?

Comment: @Nathan - New accounts are probably limited to one link to discourage spam

Comment: Instead of using the wrappers, I would suggest that you directly use Google Data API. Google has a page that details, how you can do it.
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib.html

And also look at the following : http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

This works too

Comment: @pyfunc - Is Gmail one of the services supported by the Google data API? I don't see it on this list: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gmail [supports IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=75725) and [POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=10350), which are common protocols for accessing email. You should be able to use use any working IMAP or POP library for Python to download your email. If you want tag/folder information, you'll need to stick to IMAP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know neither `libgmail` nor `gmail.py` are compatible with the current version of Gmail. I use IMAP to download mails from gmail. Python's `imaplib` module is quite useful for this.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527933/move-an-email-in-gmail-with-python-and-imaplib/3528810#3528810) (disclaimer: my answer) to a related question might give you some clues.