# Looking for a way to download inbox email

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python, looking for a way to download dump of all my emails using python. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export mail from Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592015/export-mail-from-gmail)