# How to create an email and send it to specific mailbox with imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I am trying to use python's imaplib to create an email and send it to a mailbox with specific name, e.g. INBOX. Anyone has some great suggestion :).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The IMAP protocol is not designed to send emails. It is designed to manipulate mailboxes.

To create an email and send it you can use SMTP, as in [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example).

To move an email that is already in a mailbox from one folder to another, you can copy the mail to the needed folder and delete it from the old one using `uid`, as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527933/move-an-email-in-gmail-with-python-and-imaplib/3528810#3528810).

Comment: thk:), but can i create email in specific mailbox using imaplib?

Comment: @vernomcrp: No, because as I explained imaplib cannot be used to create emails. You can send the email first then move it as above.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Python's built-in `imaplib` module and the `append()` command to append a mail message to an IMAP folder:

```
import imaplib
from email.message import Message
from time import time

connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(HOSTNAME)
connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

new_message = Message()
new_message["From"] = "hello@itsme.com"
new_message["Subject"] = "My new mail."
new_message.set_payload("This is my message.")

connection.append('INBOX', '', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time()), str(new_message).encode('utf-8'))
```

- [The official imaplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html).
- [More detailed examples of using imaplib](https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/#uploading-messages).

Comment: I have tried your method but I am getting this error:  TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object

Comment: email is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @ShahMuzaffar `email` is a package you import.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot yet comment on user3556956's comment, here is the answer for python3 :

```
connection.append('INBOX', '', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), str(new_message).encode('utf-8'))
```

In short you have to pass the message as a byte instead of a python string.

Answer (score -5):

No idea how they do it but doesn't Microsoft Outlook let you move an email from a local folder to a remote IMAP folder?