# How to reply to the last email (IMAP4) in inbox?

Tags: python, email, imap

Python IMAP4 how to reply to an email with a given UID or last email in Inbox

I have been able to login my gmail with IMAP4 and get the last UID , but I dont know how to reply to the last email in the inbox my python automation code:

```
    self.mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    self.mail.login(self.data["emailUsername"], self.data["emailPassword"]) 
    self.mail.list()
    self.mail.select("inbox")
    subjectStr = '(HEADER Subject ' + "\"" + mySubject + "\"" + ')'
    result, UIDemailsWithGivenSubject = self.mail.uid('search', None, subjectStr)
    ids_string = UIDemailsWithGivenSubject[0].decode("utf-8")
    ids_string_list = ids_string.split(" ")
    self.lastEmailUid = ids_string_list[-1]
```

Now how do I respond to the last email or respond/reply with a given UID.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the selected mailbox like this:

```
res, data = self.mail.search(None, 'ALL')
```

Your data will then look something like this: `[b'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12']` where `12` is the UID for the latest email in the selected mailbox. You can now fetch this mail with

```
self.mail.fetch(data[0].split()[-1], '(RFC822)')
```

### Explanation

`IMAP4.search(charset, criterion[, ...])` returns a list of all emails in your current mailbox. They are typically orderd by date with the first one being the oldest.
Provide `None` for the charset to search for any mail and the criterion is set to `All`.

See [Python imaplib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imaplib.html)

`data[0].split()[-1]` returns the last element (`[-1]`) of your list of mail UIDs

### Respond to mail

You are using the IMAP protocol to access a mailserver. IMAP stands for

> Internet Message Access Protocol

It is intendet for message access, not to send mail. You need SMTP to send messages. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769701/how-to-create-an-email-and-send-it-to-specific-mailbox-with-imaplib).